# MySQL Requirement to upgrade Rank

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im creating a Rank and Requirement table for Martial Arts School.

Each student holds a rank in the martial arts. The rank name, belt color, and rank requirements are stored. Each rank will have numerous rank requirements. Each requirement is considered a requirement just for the rank at which the requirement is introduced. Every requirement is associated with a particular rank. All ranks except white belt have at least one requirement.

My ER Diagram:

[Rank and Requirement ER Diagram](http://i1272.photobucket.com/albums/y394/yaeykay/Hunter%20x%20Hunter%202011/Thumbnails/eer_diagram_zpsda75b564.png)

Rank Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rank` (
  `rank_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank_nme` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`rank_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| rank_id    | INT(10)      | AUTO_INCREMENT |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
| rank_nme   | VARCHAR(45)  |                |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Requirement Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requirement` (
  `req_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rank_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `req_nme` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `req_rank_nme` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`req_id`),
  INDEX `requirement_rank_id_idx` (`rank_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `requirement_rank_id_idx`
  FOREIGN KEY (`rank_id`)
    REFERENCES `rank` (`rank_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Output:

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| req_id        | INT(10)      | AUTO_INCREMENT |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| rank_id       | INT(10)      |                |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| req_nme       | VARCHAR(45)  |                |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+
| req_rank_nme  | VARCHAR(45)  |                |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Need help if Im doing it right or wrong or you guys have modification or any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: What is `req_rank_nme` for?

Comment: The req_name is example Yellow Belt, req_rank_nme is White Belt. Basically it is requirement name you should have before you can jump for the next rank which is Yellow Belt.

Comment: I see. I suspect that that's redundant, as it will likely be the case that any rank_id will require the completion of all preceeding rank_ids - but it's basically OK.

Comment: You have example table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in the first table you will need an id that is unique and auto increment for db good practice. Then you go with the rank_id, rank_name. If you want to associate the rank with a user, you will need another foreign key to do it. user_id from users.id .

Now you have rank_id which increments and i don't see the point of doing that. The rest is ok i think.

Comment: ? There is a PK in the first table !?!?

Comment: The table should look like this : id rank_id rank_nme . Now you must fill the table with the ranks in the order of importance so the first rank you enter has rank_id 1. This is the only way you can get the importance. If you want to add an additional rank later that is in the middle you will need to alter the rank_id which is pk and is not an good ideea. It's just good practice for future edits

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary precaution in this instance.